# Is there an option for get connected remote device name in ble?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp-idf

I use esp-idf v3.0 and esp32 chip.

My esp32 is a gatt server and I communicate with a specific android app which is the gatt client.
In our system, there is a need for me to save some info for previous remote devices which were disconnected for future connection. For this reason I need some ID of the remote device, and for that I used the android bd address, but after experiments and some info from google, I understood that the bd address from android is unstable since it doesn't show the actual physical address.
Thus, I want to use the name of the android device as an ID (of course we will make sure to set our android machines to have a unique name).
But I can't find in the docs any option for reading the remote device name.

I would like to know if there is any function or example code for reading the connected devices name.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution is to pair the devices. When you do that, you get the IRK (identity resolving key) which can be used to see if a given Bluetooth device address is derived using that particular IRK.

Comment: I tried to get the IRK in ESP_GATTS_CONNECT_EVT with no success, the logic I used is: calling esp_ble_get_bond_device_num() to get the bonded devices number, after that I get the bonded devices list using esp_ble_get_bond_device_list() and then I iterate the list until I find the device with the bd address that I want, but in esp_ble_get_bond_device_num() I get zero bonded devices.